# Friends activity in /me/home

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use /me/home for get my newsfeed, but I didn't see some friends activity(comment, sharing, like). Somebody know is it possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `read_stream` permission for that, and you will most likely not get it approved:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

That being said, i am pretty sure you only get posts of friends, not comments/shares/likes. It´s about the stream, not the activity feed.

Comment: There's also a long-running open bug for this topic: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/576745515760299/